# Django 1.9 + django-cors-headers + AJAX not working

Tags: ajax, django, cors

I'm trying to do a Cross-Site communication between my Django app that returns json and a client running AJAX.

I'm using [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) with the following configuration:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  
]


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

For now I'm trying to allow all connections just to make tests.
This is my view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax:     
        results={}
        results=["The password is valid"]
        data_json=json.dumps(results)
        
    mimetype="application/json"
    return HttpResponse(data_json,mimetype)
```

I tried with the decorator @csrf_exempt too.
And finally, this is my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://otherdomain.com/myapp/",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data :{ 
            'username': $("#myName").val(),
        },
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(result){
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,error){
        alert(status);
    }
});
```

The console is alerting this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://otherdomain.com/myapp/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'thisdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Any help will be useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `dataType: "jsonp"` instead of `json`?

Comment: Hi @valentjedi thanks for your answer. I didn't try jsonp because of this comment in the django-cors-headers documentation: "Although JSON-P is useful, it is strictly limited to GET requests."

Maybe I'm not understanding well, it is possible to use POST with jsonp?

Comment: Ah I missed that. No it is not possible. Also if you use some web server like apache or nginx you should enable cors there too, not only in your django app. Check this: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I think that's the problem @valentjedi, I have the Django app in a Dreamhost shared server. Now I'm trying to enable the cors for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I can think that you forgot to enable cors support on your web server/hosting. As you use Dreamhost, you can refer to it's documentation [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216201557-How-to-setup-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-on-DreamObjects).

Also as @YPCrumble said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357024/3606603) you might want to use up to date fork [Django-cors-middleware](https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware) when you will have working requests.

Comment: Thanks @valentjedi but that's the documentation for Virtual Private Servers :/ I'm on shared hosting, and I'm starting to think that it's not allowed.

Comment: Yes, I've struggle of something similar. You may still contact support and ask them to activate CORS. Or at last stand just go to vps.

Comment: Thank you very much @valentjedi that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) is an out-of-date repo - the last commit was a year ago. You should be using [Django-cors-middleware](https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware) which is the live fork of that repo.

I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with your setup, and expect that updating the package will solve your problem. The issue is likely that you're on a new version of Django that isn't supported by the old package.

EDIT:

Based on the headers in your comment, you also need to [add an X-CsrfToken header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) to your POST request. I believe this type of cross-domain ajax request can yield the misleading CORS error, even though the issue is actually due to lack of CSRF.

The above responses work for instance if you're working with a single page application working on a separate port from your app server. However, if this is a cross-origin request to a third party server, you need to make sure that they will support CORS. If they do not, you'll need to make the POST request from your server, not the client's browser.

Comment: Hi @YPCrumble, thanks for your answer. I'm now using Django-cors-middleware.

These are my headers:

 Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* 
 Connection:Keep-Alive
 Content-Type:application/json
 Date:Wed, 13 Jul 2016 17:07:04 GMT
 Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=100
 Server:Apache
 Status:200 OK
 Transfer-Encoding:chunked
 X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
 X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger 4.0.59
Is that correct? I'm receiving the same message from AJAX.

Comment: @DavidGoudet is this a call to a truly 3rd-party API? If so, do they send CORS headers back? If not, you can't do a cross-domain request and you'll need to make the call from your server.

Comment: I don't understand, What do you mean with a truly 3rd-party API?

Comment: @DavidGoudet meaning do you control the API endpoint or is it owned by someone else (i.e., a third party). If it's controlled by a third party and they don't allow CORS then you need to find a different solution.

Comment: Oh ok.. The Django app that answer the request is mine, but the problem is that is hosted in a shared hosting (Dreamhost).