# django-cors-middleware does not work

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I've been trying django-cors-middleware for days, but I just cannot figure out how to set it up. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?
Below is the test project setting I am using.

- django-version: 1.10.3
- python-version: 3.5.2
- Project Name: cors_test
- App Name: appone
- appone/urls.py

  ```
  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.test_cors, name='test_cors'),
  ]
  ```
- appone/views.py

  ```
  def test_cors(request):
      return render(request, 'appone/test.html', {})
  ```
- appone/templates/appone/test.html

  ```
  <html>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      var url = 'https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BuxgWJ-_LIyL8QfIgYe4BQ';
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);

      xhr.onload = function() {
       var responseText = xhr.responseText;
       console.log(responseText);
      };

      xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log('There was an error!');
      };

      xhr.send();
      </script>

  </html>
  ```
- settings.py

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'corsheaders',
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
      'appone'
  ]


  MIDDLEWARE = [
      'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  ]

  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
  ```

And that's it! That is every setting, and I ran server by

```
python manage.py runserver
```

---

**Below is what I get by running above**

- error from console,

> (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BuxgWJ-_LIyL8QfIgYe4BQ. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. 
>  (index):14 There was an error!

- Request Headers

  ```
  :authority:www.google.co.jp
  :method:GET
  :path:/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BuxgWJ-_LIyL8QfIgYe4BQ
  :scheme:https
  accept:*/*
  accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
  accept-language:ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
  cache-control:no-cache
  origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
  pragma:no-cache
  referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
  user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
  x-client-data:CJe2yQEIpbbJAQjEtskBCPucygEIqZ3KAQ==
  ```
- Response Headers

  ```
  alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
  cache-control:private, max-age=0
  content-encoding:gzip
  content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
  date:Mon, 26 Dec 2016 10:48:37 GMT
  expires:-1
  p3p:CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
  server:gws
  set-cookie:NID=93=Mg89hJyAP7FyVu5AT9RzCWxyPndiWPZdKTDgipYBJhJwEBRXdMLTa5aPOBvLjVW6mwUCY1qSaOnPPIlqMvT2x1VjdoPhdlyK67ufk5bOFJJC9eKaEtfngw2xWBhSTSyI; expires=Tue, 27-Jun-2017 10:48:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.jp; HttpOnly
  status:200
  x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
  x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
  ```
- General

  ```
  Request URL:https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BuxgWJ-_LIyL8QfIgYe4BQ
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:200 
  Remote Address:216.58.197.195:443
  ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355526/django-1-9-django-cors-headers-ajax-not-working

Comment: I think my question is similar to the link above, but the solution of the link didnt help =/

Comment: The `django-cors-middleware` allows you to control access to your Django app from different domains. It doesn't let you control access to google.co.jp from your Django app. You don't control the headers that google.co.jp returns, so you can't use the middleware to enable cors.

Comment: @Alasdair ohhh... I see. That was the problem. What should I do if I want to access other web from my Django app? Can you please give me a keyword so that I can google it?

Comment: If the third party does not enable cors or jsonp, then you can't access it using javascript. You would have to fetch the content in your view instead.

Comment: So, what you mean is, if I want to access other website from my django app, I have to check the other website, not the django app. Right? So, it is all about the website getting accessed..

Comment: Can you make your comment as an answer? I will accept it as the answer of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `django-cors-middleware` app allows you to control access to your Django app from different domains. It doesn't let you control access to google.co.jp from your Django app. You don't control the headers that google.co.jp returns, so you can't use the middleware to enable cors.

If the third party does not enable cors or jsonp, then you can't access it using javascript. You'll have to fetch the content in your view instead.